# Does Service Fabric application deployment fail, because the certificate does not have a password?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-service-fabric, x509certificate, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure pipeline, which works pretty well with a self-signed certificate:

It deploys (via ARM templates) Redis, CosmosDB, EventHub, Keyvault, then imports the self-signed certificate into the Keyvault, then deploys SF cluster and configures it with the certificate.

Finally the pipeline deploys our team's application with the following task:

```
- task: ServiceFabricDeploy@1
  displayName: 'Deploy SF app'
  inputs:
    applicationPackagePath: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\Release\Applications\CloudGateway\Pkg\release'
    serviceConnectionName: '${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionName }}'
    applicationParameterPath: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\Release\Applications\CloudGateway\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml'
    overwriteBehavior: 'SameAppTypeAndVersion'
    overridePublishProfileSettings: true
    upgradeMode: 'UnmonitoredAuto'
    FailureAction: 'Rollback'
```

It works well, for days and in 5 different pipelines (1 scheduled for nights, 3 manual and 1 used for our Pull Request builds).

My problem:

I am trying to switch from using a self-signed certificate to a real wildcard certificate issued by DigiCert.

And then the final [ServiceFabricDeploy@1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ServiceFabricDeployV1) task fails with

> An error occurred attempting to import the certificate. Ensure that your service endpoint is configured properly with a correct certificate value and, if the certificate is password-protected, a valid password. Error message: Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct.

[image: error screenshot]

When I go to my resource group and verify that everything is deployed properly, I can not find any problems.

The SF cluster is configured with the new DigiCert certificate:

[image: SF screenshot]

And I have updated the SF service connection with the new hostname, certificate thumbprint and base64-encoded certificate contents as well:

[image: service connection]

The only difference I see to the self-signed certificate, which I was using before and for which the Service Fabric app deployment worked is that it had a password.

While the new DigiCert-issued certificate does not have a password.

Is that the reason why the error message mentions that the third argument is missing?

I have searched for way to add a password to a certificate (either manually or by a PowerShell command) and have not found any.

I have create [Github issue #13079](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13079) for my problem and also asked at [Microsoft forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1067937/servicefabricdeploy.html).

**UPDATE:**

I've decided to add [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-setup) to our SF cluster setup - and will configure the Digicert certificate there, while keeping the self-signed certificate for SF node-to-node comms.

Comment: You can add a certificate by importing it on your machine and then export it, including private key and with a password. More info [here](https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/import-and-export-certificate-microsoft-windows)

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security#cluster-and-server-certificate-required): "The certificate must contain a private key"

Comment: There is private key, but no password. I will try @LoekD suggestion and report back. Also I start thinking if my overall setup is correct... Wouldn't then anyone be able to connect to my SF explorer? Maybe I should stick with a self-signed cert and then have some reverse proxy with the DigiCert cert in front of my SF cluster app