# Service Fabric, Azure Devops Deployment fails : The specified network password is not correct

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault, serviceconnection

I was recently ordered by our IT team to disable the NAT pools on my service fabric cluster due to security risks. The only way I could do this was to deploy a new cluster with all its components.

Because this is a test environment I opt to use a self signed cert without a password for my cluster, the certificate is in my vault and the cluster is up and running.

The issue I have now is when I try to deploy my application from an Azure Devops Release Pipeline I get the following message:

> An error occurred attempting to import the certificate. Ensure that your service endpoint is configured properly with a correct certificate value and, if the certificate is password-protected, a valid password. Error message: Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct.

I generated the self signed certificate in Key Vault, downloaded the certificate and used Powershell to get the Base64 string for the service connection.

Should I create the certificate myself, with a password?

Comment: See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245798/does-service-fabric-application-deployment-fail-because-the-certificate-does-no#comment110108032_62245798).  The certificate must contain a private key and password.  You can use OpenSSL to add a password.

Comment: to be pedantic... you need a certificate and private key. the public key is in the cert. the cert does not contain a private key. if you're creating a self-signed cert in KV, then you will need to download a PFX file, and not a CER file. A PFX file is the cert + private key and a CER file is *only* the cert. IIRC, KV *does not* download a pwd-encrypted PFX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the direction of the two comments supplied, I ended up generating a certificate on my local machine using the powershell script included with service fabric's local run time.

A small caveat here is to change the key size in the script to a large key size than the default, because ke vault does not support 1024 keys.

I then exported the pfx from my user certificates added a password(this is required for the service connection) and impoted the new pfx into my key vault.

Redeployed my cluster and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, there is very little documentation around this kind of thing, I inderstand we can't cover all the bases but this seems like a very general setup.

Just a question if you could find out, why does Key vault not have an option to create a certificate with a password?